# C++ deduced incomplete pack on generic variadic template function

Tags: c++, generics, variadic-templates, c++-concepts

Given the following code:

```cpp
template <class P>
concept Pair = requires(P pair)
{
    typename P::first_type;
    typename P::second_type;
    pair.first;
    pair.second;
    { pair.first } -> std::same_as<typename P::first_type &>;
    { pair.second } -> std::same_as<typename P::second_type &>;
};

template <typename T>
setTag(const std::string_view key, const T &value)
{
    foo(key.data(), value);
    // things in here
}

template <Pair... Pairs>
void setTags(Pairs... pairs)
{
    ((setTag(std::get<0>(pairs), std::get<1>(pairs)), ...));
}
```

To invoke `setTags`, it is mandatory to declare a pair on every parameter pack:

```cpp
setTags(std::make_pair("key1", 1),
        std::make_pair("key2", "example"),
        std::make_pair("key3", std::set{1, 2}));
```

I've been looking for a while a way of invoking this function without needing to explicitly use `make_pair` function, such as this:

```cpp
setTags({"key1", 1},
        {"key2", "example"},
        {"key3", std::set{1, 2}});
```

But this throws following compile error:

```
note: candidate template ignored: substitution failure: deduced incomplete pack <(no value), (no value), (no value)> for template parameter 'Pairs'
```

This makes some sense because compiler is not able to deduce the type of the parameters in the pack.
That's why I introduced the C++20 concept in order to somehow force the typing, but it does not work.

Some approaches:

1. Using a json library such as `nlohmann_json` and accept json arguments but this introduces a undesired dependency.
2. Use `std::initializer_list`, something like this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
void setTags(std::initializer_list<std::pair<std::string,T>> pairs)
{
    for(const auto &[key, value] : pairs){
        setTag(key, value);
    }
}
```

But the problem here is that we lose the genericity by having to specify the type of the values which have to be the same...

```cpp
setTags<int>({{"key1", 1}, {"key2",2}});
```

**=== EDIT ===**

As some folks suggest, here is a concept that checks `std::pair` and `std::get` and `first` to be a string type (as the key in key-value tags)

```cpp
template <typename P>
concept KeyValuePair = requires(P pair) {
    typename std::decay_t<P>::first_type;
    typename std::decay_t<P>::second_type;

    { std::get<0>(pair) } -> std::convertible_to<typename std::decay_t<P>::first_type>;
    { std::get<1>(pair) } -> std::convertible_to<typename std::decay_t<P>::second_type>;

    std::is_convertible_v<typename std::decay_t<P>::first_type, std::string>;
};
```

And a shorter version using `CTAD`

```cpp
setTags(std::pair("key1", 1),
        std::pair("key2", "example"),
        std::pair("key3", std::set{1, 2}));
```

Comment: Your `Pair` concept still needs to check the type, and `{ val1, val2 }` has no type.  You can shorten the code a little bit now that we have CTAD and `std::make_pair("key1", 1)` can be shortened to `std::pair{"key1", 1}`

Comment: [OT]: your constraint doesn't force `std::get<0>(pairs)` to be valid.

Comment: @Jarod42 didnt understand last one, I'm not a concept expert.

Comment: @NathanOliver yea, catcha, thanks for than shortening. But is it possible to dont use even `std::pair` but nothing?

Comment: The only trick I know is the initializer list one, but that doesn't work for you.

Comment: Also, Jarod is pointing out that your `Pair` concept does not check if using `get` on the type is valid or not.  Since your function uses `get`, your concept should be checking for it.  You could have a type that satisfies your concept but that does not work with `get` and your concept will erroneously accept that.

Answer (score 2):

`{..}` has no type and so cannot be deduced with `T` (constrainted or not).

One workaround might be to flatten the pairs:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2, typename... Ts>
void setTags(T1 t1, T2 t2, Ts... ts)
{
    setTag(t1, t2);
    if constexpr (sizeof...(Ts) > 0) 
    {
        setTags(ts...);
    }
}
```

With call

```
setTags("key1", 1,
        "key2", "example",
        "key3", std::set{1, 2});
```

[Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e5MY8vWMs)

Comment: This is a really good example of variadic templates usage I didnt know about!

Comment: I appreciate your time, saddly, this will make `setTags` invokation really messy and confussing. I'll be nice to have somehow a "separator" just to split the key-value pairs. Maybe some trick using the (, ) comma operator or something?

Comment: Then `std::pair` to group seems better than a separator ;-)